# Telegram Bot - How to set a timeout for each state / session in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Currently I'm creating a simple game bot in telegram. I'm just curious, what's the best approach to create a service in PHP that can tell the Telegram Bot if the session or the time already out.

For example, in my bot, I will create a Room for each game invoked by the player. And each player got 5 seconds to answer the question. The room has its own duration, and each player has their own duration too (5 seconds). How can I tell the telegram Bot for :

1. The room already expired (e.g. 10 mins), tell the telegram to send the message to the room.
2. Player A can't answer the question in given time (5 seconds). How to tell the telegram if the Player A failed to answer the question. Then send the message to the room for the info.

I can do these 2 question if the api is invoked by the telegram, but how if the telegram didn't invoke my api?

Thanks.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard about Telegram bot, but i don't know if is helpful in your case to use `mktime();` function, for example:

```
    $a = mktime();
    $b = $a + 5;
    if ($a == $b)
    timeout();
```

mktime() get Unix timestamp for a date and since it generates a number based on the system's time, you can check if has passed the 5 seconds or not.

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. But you have to revisit the page again to check whether $a == $b or not right? I mean, is there anyway to automatically timeout without revisit the page?

Comment: well to be honest I'm not an expert in web developing, I'm kinda noob to but if you use for example ajax, a javascript technique you can talk to the server without reloading the page, even you can use javascript for making the count of seconds to, but since javascript is client side can be manipulated throw the browser inspect element, so as far as i know use ajax and i think that you will be ok.. Here is a link of w3school where you can study the basic of ajax http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp